# Alfresco Java backed web-script lookup by cmis:objectId

Tags: alfresco, cmis, opencmis

I am writing my first java-backed webscript for Alfresco community edition. I am implementing document properties / preview service, and I take a parameter which is the cmis:objectId of the document in question.  I'm having trouble getting started because I haven't been able to access the document based on the cmis id.

What is the best way to get a document (NodeRef?) based on the cmis:objectId when operating server-side in a web-script controller?  I see Jeff Potts' great examples on how to implement web scripts, but the mixing of the Java API and CMIS concepts has me stuck.  Should I just use the search service and find the object based on the cmis:objectId property?  Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: What version of Alfresco are you targetting? 4.x? 5.0?

Comment: Sorry... version 4.2e

Comment: The `cmis:objectId` is supposed to be opaque to the calling code, and may (+does!) change between implementations and versions. However, if you just want to target only Alfresco 4.2, then the object ID is basically an Alfresco NodeRef, so tweak+use as normal!

Comment: Thanks much, I see how that would work. What if I wanted to do it the "right" way, treating the objectid as opaque? There's a good chance we'll upgrade to 5.x prior to production, and I'd like to have robust code. Am I using the search?

Comment: Personally, I'd probably find the code in the Alfresco CMIS bridge to Apache Chemisty OpenCMIS that converts NodeRefs to/from object IDs, and call that from my webscript!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the answer is a little ugly, but hopefully this helps someone...

A good way to look up the NodeRef using an 'opaque' objectId *should* be to use CMISServices, obtained from the registry in your java backed web script, i.e.

```
docRef = registry.getCMISService().getLatestVersion(docIdStr, false);
```

Unfortunately, there's a bug in the Alfresco code (or so it seems to me, admittedly a bit of a newbie).  The alfresco CMISServicesImpl.getLatestVersion() uses a getObject() method under the covers.  That method takes an objectId String as a parameter, but then strips off the version information at the end (i.e. the ";1.0" part of the objectId) and then checks to see if the remaining string is a valid NodeRef.  In doing so, it checks it against this pattern (in NodeRef.java):

```
private static final Pattern nodeRefPattern = Pattern.compile(".+://.+/.+");
```

If the validation fails, you get a CMISInvalidArgumentException, with a message that xxxxx "is not an object ID".

So, to make a long story short, when I call the web script using a parameter for the objectId like this:

```
29ea5a16-12a8-497d-aad3-f43969e8a672;1.0
```

I get the CMIS exception. But, if I call the method with an objectId parameter that looks like this:

```
workspace://SpacesStore/29ea5a16-12a8-497d-aad3-f43969e8a672;1.0
```

... then, the "CMIS" lookup succeeds and I get my desired NodeRef back.  Of course, all that the CMIS services are doing under the covers is stripping off the ";1.0" from the object ID, treating it as a NodeRef string, and doing the lookup using that.
In other words, you can't do it the right way in 4.2.  The best thing to do is as @Gagravarr says and tweak your own objectId string to turn it into a NodeRef.  Hopefully it's fixed in 5.x.